# Publish web site vs web app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013

I installed vs 2013 in my laptop with azure SDK. I want to publish my site in window azure . Its my website not web application. When I right click to publish my site I am surprise there is not any option to Publish Web Site .Instead of this I find publish web app. In my desk top it work fine and able to  Publish web site.May I missing to install some thing in my laptop?

Any help would be much appreciated  . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a website, there's no need to publish, you just copy the files to the server and the server will take care of the build steps. Which is why Visual Studio will give you a Copy Website Option instead of a Publish option.

If you don't like it, you can switch it to a web application, which seems to be what most people use.